# Restricting keyboard strokes to single process

Tags: c++, windows, directx

I have one game running and I am trying to show one overlay in the game; where user can enter his details. The problem here is the keystrokes entered by user are available to game source and I want to limit the keystrokes to overlay only. 
I am using native c++ dll to show the overlay which uses CEF to to render the content.
Is there any way available to do this thing in secure manner so user details won't be exposed to any other program/process.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried e.handled = true in the keydown event?

Comment: @Alain: What? There's nothing like that in a Windows message.

Comment: @DeadMG [`System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx#Y0)`->`[`Handled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled.aspx). The question wasn't clear enough to rule out the possibility of it being relevant.

Comment: Thanks Alain and DeadMG. Sorry if my question is not clear enough. We are not using forms so KeyPressEvents is not useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [SetWindowHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This way you can hook all keyboard messages that are send to a process and stop delivering them altogether (and process them in your own app without having focus for example). It is a quite robust way but some copy protections might not like it.

The normal steps are:

- Create a DLL (must be because you need to load it into another process/address space) that hooks the windows messages and does the first filtering. Usually you use some IPC mechanism to get the formation to your own process. If you only hook mouse messages you could use Windows messages to send the info to one hidden message of your own. If you do not want the message to arrive you can stop the chain there.
- When the IPC call arrives in your own window; process it as if you got the keyboard message yourself. Try to be careful with focus etc.

The only thing you cannot catch in this manner is if the application behaviour you try to alter is dependent on [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(). In such a case you're only option is to use inject your DLL into the other address space and hook the call itself but that is higher-level-hacking.

One word of advice: when developing windows hooking software: save often, save often! If you make a mistake you might crash a whole slew of applications in one go...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried blocking the keyboard messages using SetWindowHookEx, still it didn't prevent the game from getting the keyboard strokes.

Comment: @Raj: I would say your first action should be: determine how  the game detects keyboard events; apparently it is not normal WM_KEY* messages. It can be async, low level keyboard messages perhaps it hooks the messages itself etc. Without this information it is shooting in the dark..

Comment: I am using games based on the Unity framework. It uses Input Manager and Events class to get the keystrokes and I believe these two classes operate on windows loop. I had a little success in this. I used direct input with exclusive keyboard access inside my native dll and it prevented the game to get any keystrokes. But catch here is if anyone else mimic the direct input behavior in their native code, they can also get the keystrokes.